# AWS CodeDeploy redeployment from command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-code-deploy

Is it possible to retry/redeploy a previously successful deployment through command line? I know a list of deployments can be fetched from command line using 
`aws deploy list-deployments` but I didn't find any option to rerun the deployment using deployment-id returned from this command.
There is an option to retry a previously run deployment from console though.

Comment: Pretty sure the "retry" button under the hood just creates a new build with the same params as the old.

Comment: Yes, there is an option for retry in console but I don't see any option to do a retry from command line. I guess I'd need to use aws deploy create-deployment for retry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-deployment is simply based on creating **new-deployment** using a previous version of your application. Unfortunately, there is no special `redeploy` command for that.

In the docs there is [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorials-windows-update-and-redeploy-application.html#tutorials-windows-update-and-redeploy-application-deploy-updates-cli) **how to redeploy** sample project:

```
aws deploy create-deployment --application-name HelloWorld_App --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime --deployment-group-name HelloWorld_DepGroup --s3-location bucket=codedeploydemobucket,bundleType=zip,key=HelloWorld_App.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bash script that finds the last successful deployment and deploys that.  With a few simple changes you could

- deploy the last successful blue deployment to green
- specify a deployment-config-name or description
- add a `wait deployment-successful` then a notification or another action

```
applicationName="my-application-name"
deploymentGroupName="my-deployment-group"
lastSuccessfulDeployment=$(aws deploy list-deployments --application-name $applicationName --deployment-group-name $deploymentGroupName --include-only-statuses "Succeeded" --query 'deployments[0]' --output text)
s3Location=$(aws deploy get-deployment --deployment-id $lastSuccessfulDeployment --query 'deploymentInfo.revision.s3Location')
aws deploy create-deployment --application-name $applicationName --deployment-group-name $deploymentGroupName --s3-location $s3Location
```

Comment: thanks for the tip Andrew!
Unfortunately, your script hasn't worked for me as is, so I came up with my version, it would be beneficial for those who use revisions instead of s3Location
https://gist.github.com/etolbakov/ce3a49393d8247bbe05afc2a5730a3d8

Answer (score 0):

Clubbing other answers, I was able to make it work as below:

```
REGION=us-east-1
applicationName="MyApp"
deploymentGroupName="MyDeploymentGroup"
lastSuccessfulDeployment=$(aws deploy list-deployments --application-name $applicationName --deployment-group-name $deploymentGroupName --include-only-statuses "Succeeded" --query 'deployments[0]' --output text --region $REGION)
echo "lastSuccessfulDeployment: $lastSuccessfulDeployment"

s3LocationBucket=$(aws deploy get-deployment --deployment-id $lastSuccessfulDeployment --query 'deploymentInfo.revision.s3Location.bucket' --region $REGION --output text)
echo "s3LocationBucket: $s3LocationBucket"

s3LocationKey=$(aws deploy get-deployment --deployment-id $lastSuccessfulDeployment --query 'deploymentInfo.revision.s3Location.key' --region $REGION --output text)
echo "s3LocationKey: $s3LocationKey"

deploymentId=$(aws deploy create-deployment --application-name $applicationName --deployment-group-name $deploymentGroupName --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce --s3-location bucket=$s3LocationBucket,bundleType=zip,key=$s3LocationKey --region $REGION --query 'deploymentId' --output text)
echo "deploymentId: $deploymentId"

aws deploy wait deployment-successful --deployment-id $deploymentId --region $REGION
```